# How to pass object json in components -REACTJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

How can pass JSON PagePJ in DetailsPJ in component details .

I am loading pj in json and i want to pass details json in component DetailsPJ when user click the card.

How i can pass object?¿

How can use Route for this or what is the best way for pass object in components.

**PaginaPersonajes**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';
import { PaginaPlataformas } from './PaginaPlataformas';
import { PaginaJuegos } from './PaginaJuegos';
import { DetallesPersonajes } from './DetallesPersonajes';
import data from "../JSON/Personajes.json";


import './Personajes.css';
import { CargarDatos } from './CargarDatos'

import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link
} from "react-router-dom";


export class PaginaPersonajes extends Component {



    click(e) {
        //const mother = new Mother();
        //mother.addMother(id);


        console.log();

    }

    render() {


        console.log('-> render')
        return (
            <div className="fondodepantalla">



                <Router>


                {data.map((perso, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={perso.Nombre} className="MoviesList-item">






                    <ReactBootstrap.Card  onClick={this.click} href="http://escuela.it " style={{ width: '15rem' }}>
                    <ReactBootstrap.Nav.Link href="/DetallesPersonajes" >Personajes</ReactBootstrap.Nav.Link> 
                    <Link to='/DetallesPersonajes2'>Tyler McGinnis</Link>
                    <Link
                    to={{ pathname: '/DetallesPersonajes2/'+perso.Nombre}}
                    className="list-group-item"
                    key={perso.Nombre}>
                    {perso.Nombre}
                     </Link>
                     <Link to={{ pathname: '/DetallesPersonajes', query: { the: perso.Nombre } }}>eeeee </Link>

                    { /*<ReactBootstrap.Nav.Link to="/DetallesPersonajes" title="Index Page" >Personajes</ReactBootstrap.Nav.Link> */}

                        {/*Para coger la carpeta public */}
                        <ReactBootstrap.Card.Img variant="top" src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + perso.Foto}  alt="Error" />
                        <ReactBootstrap.Card.Body>
                            <ReactBootstrap.Card.Title>{perso.Nombre}</ReactBootstrap.Card.Title>
                            <ReactBootstrap.Card.Text>         {perso.Descripcion}    </ReactBootstrap.Card.Text>

                        </ReactBootstrap.Card.Body>
                        <Switch>
                    {/* Rutas de las paginas */}



                    <Route
                    path='/DetallesPersonajes2:id'
                    render={(props) => <DetallesPersonajes data={perso} {...props} />}
                />




                    </Switch>

                    </ReactBootstrap.Card>
                    </div>



);
})}
                </Router>

            </div>
        )
    }



}
```

**DetallesPersonajes.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';
import data from "../JSON/Personajes.json";
import { PaginaJuegos } from './PaginaJuegos';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link
} from "react-router-dom";



export class DetallesPersonajes extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        //PARA MODIFICAR ELEMENTOS DEL STATE HACE FALTA PONER EL .SETINTERVAL , cada segundo suma +1 al contador
        debugger;
      }





    render(){
        this.forceUpdate() 
        console.log(this.props.persona.Nombre)
        return (


            <div>
                      <p>{ this.props.persona.Nombre}</p>



            </div>

        )
    }

}
```